# Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Studio 1558 Laptop?

Tags: drivers, dell

I was just wondering if it would be possible to put 12.04 on my Dell Studio 1558. I was poking around the Ubuntu website, and other websites and was unable to find any specific drivers for this model of laptop.

Does anyone know where I could find the appropriate drivers so I can get a better grip if ubuntu is right for me?

Thank you

Comment: You may not need any. Try a live USB or DVD without installing first. If you have problems you can ask specific questions about what's not working otherwise install.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer. You should just be able to install it without any issues. The only problem I have ever had is with nvidea video cards and that was a while ago and, if I recall correctly, only on the install media not on the installation itself. I have found that as long as you can see, you can fix any problem with ubuntu. I did a quick poke-around and according to amazon your graphics card is radeon, here is a list of supported cards https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver. There is a slim possibility that you will not have the supported drivers for your wifi card, but ubuntu won't let you install without a connection so you'd know.

Answer (score 0):

The best part is you are having Dell , What all you need to do is Install Ubuntu with consideration of Ubuntu System Architecture and after installation completes install all needed softwares and do -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then Ubuntu Software Center and click on edit and then Software Sources in that go to additional drivers as shown below -

[image: here]

and your driver consideration is done, it will automatically additional driver for **wifi** and **Graphic card** if needed.

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dell machines have been pretty well supported on Ubuntu ever since Dell started selling laptops with Ubuntu pre-installed.

The only way to know for sure though is to run the live environment from a CD/DVD or USB.

Check out [Ubuntu's guide to trying Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install), and make sure you click "Try Ubuntu" first!